# What's the pythonic way to deal with worker processes that must coordinate their tasks?

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing

I'm currently learning Python (from a Java background), and I have a question about something I would have used threads for in Java.

My program will use workers to read from some web-service some data periodically. Each worker will call on the web-service at various times periodically.

From what I have read, it's preferable to use the `multiprocessing` module and set up the workers as independent processes that get on with their data-gathering tasks. On Java I would have done something conceptually similar, but using threads. While it appears I can use threads in Python, I'll lose out on multi-cpu utilisation.

Here's the guts of my question: The web-service is throttled, viz., the workers must not call on it more than x times per second. What is the best way for the workers to check on whether they may request data?

I'm confused as to whether this should be achieved using:

- Pipes as a way to communicate to some other 'managing object', which monitors the total calls per second.
- Something along the lines of `nmap`, to share some data/value between the processes that describes if they may call the web-service.
- A `Manager()` object that monitors the calls per seconds and informs workers if they have permission to make their calls.

Of course, I guess this may come down to how I keep track of the calls per second. I suppose one option would be for the workers to call a function on some other object, which makes the call to the web-service and records the current number of calls/sec. Another option would be for the function that calls the web-service to live within each worker, and for them to message a managing object every time they make a call to the web-service.

Thoughts welcome!

Comment: Incidentally, if waiting for data from the web service is the main bottleneck, threads will work in Python. The threads can sleep while they're waiting for the network. Doesn't answer your question, but worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks. I guess you're right; I think I'm just exploring the process approach as it's a good excuse to learn a new application of the `multiprocessing` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegate the retrieval to a separate process which queues the requests until it is their turn.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't very clear on this. Each worker has its own data-feed that it needs to retrieve from, thus they all need to be retrieving separately. While this could be done by one process if the workers specify where to get the data from, all the data needs to be as fresh as possible (order of seconds), and I'm concerned about the freshness of data when queueing multiple web-service requests, as opposed to making them in parallel.

Comment: If the web service is throttled then queueing the requests in one place is the only way to be sure that you don't exceed it. If there needs to be some sort of parallelism on the other end of the queue then so be it, but you can't get away from the throttling.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you'll find that the `multiprocessing` module will provide you with some fairly familiar constructs.

You might find that `multiprocessing.Queue` is useful for connecting your worker threads back to a managing thread that could provide monitoring or throttling.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question, but an alternative approach to your problem: You could get rid of synchronization issues when doing requests event driven, e.g. by using the [Python async module](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html) or [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/). You wouldn't benefit from multiple CPUs/cores, but in context of network communication that's usually negligible.

Comment: Twisted looks interesting. Thanks.